# Best practices for providing dynamic content 'drop in' widgets for third party websites?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, affiliate

I am wondering what best practices are for providing dynamic content in lightweight, 'drop in' widget style that can be used by third party content editors.

To elaborate, we would like to give third parties the ability to show dynamic content from us on their website without a back end system integration where they would have to call one of our APIs server side - ideally it would be possible for their content editors simply to include a provided snippit in their HTML. A concrete example would be a bestseller list that changes every few hours.

Using an IFRAME is one obvious way of accomplishing this, but I'm curious if there are others that allow tighter integration into their source and more flexible styling and are 'expected best practice' for such an offering as it isn't a field I know well - JavaScript/JSON perhaps?

Comment: I would suggest the use of an iframe ... it's simple. it works. it has an installed base that understands it.

Comment: Let me not be as snarky. Are you looking for them to write the least amount of code on their end, or the tightest integration into their page even if they have to write/maintain lots of code?

Comment: @drachenstern, I'd ideally like to expose multiple options, with one on each end of that spectrum.  From the responses I've seen, it looks like IFRAME and JSONP may be those two.

Comment: ~ My point is that asking someone else to install your code on their server to work with your data is potentially a bad thing.  Maybe I'm just too cynical. Maybe I'm just too oldschool. I would rather use the iframe approach. That's just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative to iFrames: [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP)**

JSONP is used by Javascript widget libraries to pull in data from the widget library's server since JSONP gets around the same-origin issues.

This enables your JS widget library to provide data and UI services to the hosting page without any changes to the hosting page's server.

It's clean, neat, and avoids various iframe issues.

As mentioned in other answers, anyone including your JS in their pages is trusting that your JS is not a security/privacy issue. But that's not a problem depending on your relationship with the folks who'd include your library.

Comment: Thank you that looks good - do any browsers or common security settings try and block JSONP style <script> sources or tags?

Comment: Nothing blocks JSONP since it is implemented by adding a script el to the dom dynamically, and all the browsers support that. Also, there is JSONP support from YUI, JQuery and other libraries.

Comment: Note that the security issue is exactly the same as with JavaScript, the page has no way of blocking JavaScript in the JSON file.

Answer (score 3):

I'd call an iframe best practice since it does not grant the framed content any excess rights, but having a JavaScript file that other sites can include seems pretty common as well, so you could probably get a lot of site owners to accept that. Still, the iframe is preferable, you shouldn't use JavaScript unless it really makes a difference.

You can easily make the to-be-iframed page configurable through parameters in the link, so site owners can set things like background and font to match their own site.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you're opening a potential security Pandora's box. Take a look at the [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) project, it allows to safely embed untrusted JavaScript content.

Comment: AFAIK, not if the site trusts us?  I don't see the risk to us - if there is one please elaborate